# Как преобразовать State в int?

Tags: python, aiogram, state, qiwi

Я делаю бота с подписками и для этого надо как то пополнять баланс что очевидно, я сделал это при помощи Qiwi.
В тестах я использовал фиксированную стоимость с помощью переменной, сейчас же я решил сделать так что бы пользователь смог сам указывать сумму пополнения, однако я получаю ошибку когда сравниваю количество пришедших денег и число которое ввёл пользователь.
Так же прикладываю весь код платёжки с ошибкой(ошибка в строке 84).

```
from misc import bot, dp, conn, cursor
from .functions import *
import requests
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import Helper, HelperMode, ListItem
import os
import json
from config import *  # именно в конфиге находятся все данные киви
import random
import time
from time import gmtime
from time import strftime
import handlers.keyboard as kb
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram import executor, types
from aiogram.utils.helper


class st(StatesGroup):
    item = State()


@dp.message_handler(text=['Пополнения и подписки'])
async def fag(message: types.Message):
    user = message.from_user
    chat = message.chat
    balance = await get_balance(message)
    podpiska = await get_podp(message)
    if podpiska == 0:
        podp = "нету"
    else:
        get = cursor.execute("SELECT podp_time FROM users WHERE id=?", (user.id,)).fetchall()
        ptime = f"{int(get[0][0])}"
        podp_time = time.time() - float(ptime)
        vremya = strftime("%j дней %H часов %M минут", gmtime(podp_time))
        podp = f"осталось <code>{vremya}</code>"
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"<b>Баланс:</b> <code>{balance}</code>\n"
                                            f"<b>Подписка:</b> {podp}", reply_markup=kb.qiw)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == "popol")
async def show(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, "Введите сумму пополнения", reply_markup=kb.back)
    await st.item.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=st.item)
async def proc(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == 'Отмена':
        await message.answer('Отмена! Возвращаю назад.', reply_markup=kb.menu)
        await state.finish()
    else:
        if message.text.isdigit():
            coment = ''.join(random.choices('qwertyuiopsdfghjkl;zxcvbnm', k=10)) + str(random.randint(1, 1000))
            amount = message.text
            s = requests.Session()
            s.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer' + token
            parameters = {'publicKey': publick_key, 'amount': message.text, 'phone': phone, 'comment': coment}
            h = s.get('https://oplata.qiwi.com/create', params=parameters)
            inlinepay_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            pay_sub = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пополнить баланс', url=h.url)
            check_pay = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Проверить оплату QIWI', callback_data='checkpay')
            inlinepay_keyboard = inlinepay_keyboard.add(pay_sub).add(check_pay)
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Для оплаты нажмите на кнопку ниже.',
                                   reply_markup=inlinepay_keyboard)

            new_payment(message.chat.id, coment, amount)
            await state.finish()
        else:
            await message.answer('Вы вводите буквы...\nВведите цифры')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='checkpay')
async def check_payment(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    coment = get_comment(query.message.chat.id)
    s = requests.Session()
    s.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
    parameters = {'rows': '50', 'operation': 'IN'}
    h = s.get('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v1/persons/' + phone + '/payments', params=parameters)
    result = json.loads(h.text)
    for i in range(len(result['data'])):
        if result['data'][i]['coment'] == str(coment):
            if result['data'][i]['sum']['amount'] >= st.item:  # как раз таки место с ошибкой
                await bot.send_message(query.message.chat.id, 'Оплата прошла,добавил вас в базу')
                add_sub(query.message.chat.id)
                break
            else:
                await bot.send_message(query.message.chat.id, 'Не нашел вашу оплату')
                break
```

Comment: Можете хотя бы сам текст ошибки прислать?

Comment: Да забыл код ошибки, вот он: TypeError: 'State' object is not subscriptable

Comment: А что вы хотите этим сделать if result['data'][i]['sum']['amount'] >= st.item ?

Comment: Если сумма платежа больше или равна указанной то, *код дальше*

Comment: так получается бред же, нет? st.item это состояние. Почему вы сравниваете состояние и число? Где по вашему должно быть число для сравнения? Не вижу чтобы вы ложили его в стейт

Comment: Да, я вот и думаю как мне это сделать?

Comment: Ну так а с каким числом вы сравнивать хотите? Должен же быть какой-то список или словарь или бд где лежат цены

Comment: В бд записывается сумма которую должен был пополнить человек... Стоп, спасибо, я сам разобрался в своём коде)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой, решение: записывайте в бд сумму пополнения в отдельный столбец и уже его сравнивайте с пришедшим платежом

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).